# SharePoint 2013 custom navigation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to customize sharepoint 2013 navigation. I am following this example:

http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/customizing-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-part-2/

but the issue is where i would put the repeater control in my master page? sharepoint 2013 only allows editing .html files?

Comment: What do you mean "SharePoint 2013 allows editing html files only"? You can deploy custom master pages using features in SharePoint. It may depend on type of solution you use though. Are you developing farm solution or sharepoint app?

Comment: Dear i have converted master page from html file. Now there is one .master file and one.html file. I can only edit .html files.?

Comment: You need to have master page file and deploy it to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit both the HTML or .master page (though editing the .master is not recommended). Are you able to use the design manager on the site to generate the necessary snippet that you can place in the .html? In the example you linked, it looks like he is using the top navigation. You can do the same for the .html page by generating a snippet for the top navigation and pasting it to where ever you want in your .html master page.